# Use Jhi Translate in typescript file

Tags: angular, jhipster

I use Angular 6 and JHipster 5.2.1

As it's available in html:

```
<span jhiTranslate="myapp.vehicule.reinitialiser">Réinitialiser</span>
```

I would like to do it in typescript.

```
 const btnCancelText = this.jhiTranslateComponent.translateValues("myapp.vehicule.reinitialiser");
```

I don't know how to do it. Could you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind. I found it using:

const btnCancelText = this.translate.instant("myapp.vehicule.reinitialiser");

Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you need to import in your component to be able to do that? New component simply states: "Property 'translate' does not exist on type ..."

Comment: Hello, you need to insert private translate : TranslateService in your constructor in your controller. This service come from this import: import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';